# Change Dropdown value based on checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm a bit stuck and not quite understanding why.  I'm working within a pre-existing box that requires us to create a work-around - to simplify the explanation, basically what I need to do is populate a dropdown list with the value of a selected checkbox.

I've gotten the basics of that to work with the following code:

```
<h4>Select a Date:</h4>
<input type="checkbox" id="session_1" value="1" name="this">Session 1
<br>      
<input type="checkbox" id="session_2" value="2" name="this">Session 2
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="session_3" value="3" name="this">Session 3
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="session_4" value="4" name="this">Session 4
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="session_5" value="5" name="this">Session 5
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="session_6" value="6" name="this">Session 6
<br>
<br/><br/>
<select id="hidden_select">
    <option>-</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
</select>
```

and the jQuery:

```
$(':checkbox').on('change',function(){
 var th = $(this), name = th.prop('name'); 
 if(th.is(':checked')){
     $(':checkbox[name="'  + name + '"]').not($(this)).prop('checked',false);   
  }
});

$('input#session_1').on('change', function () {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
          $('#hidden_select>option:eq(1)').attr('selected', true);
      } else {
          $('#hidden_select>option:eq(1)').attr('selected', false);
      }
  });

$('input#session_2').on('change', function () {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
          $('#hidden_select>option:eq(2)').attr('selected', true);
      } else {
          $('#hidden_select>option:eq(2)').attr('selected', false);
      }
  });

  $('input#session_3').on('change', function () {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
          $('#hidden_select>option:eq(3)').attr('selected', true);
      } else {
          $('#hidden_select>option:eq(3)').attr('selected', false);
      }
  });

  $('input#session_4').on('change', function () {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
          $('#hidden_select>option:eq(4)').attr('selected', true);
      } else {
          $('#hidden_select>option:eq(4)').attr('selected', false);
      }
  });

  $('input#session_5').on('change', function () {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
          $('#hidden_select>option:eq(5)').attr('selected', true);
      } else {
          $('#hidden_select>option:eq(5)').attr('selected', false);
      }
  });

  $('input#session_6').on('change', function () {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
          $('#hidden_select>option:eq(6)').attr('selected', true);
      } else {
          $('#hidden_select>option:eq(6)').attr('selected', false);
      }
  });
```

You can see the [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/qnd75wmf/4/).

This works if you were to click one option and be done with it, or click different boxes in sequential order (1-6), but if you change your mind and go back (Select 1, then 4, then go back to one) the dropdown no longer updates.

Any thoughts as to why it stops recognizing the change?  Is there a way to get past it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your options in your `select` are staying selected even after you click on a different checkbox. When you set one of the options to `selected`, make sure you remove the `selected` attribute from other options:

```
  $('input#session_3').on('change', function () {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
          //PUT THIS LINE ON EACH OF YOUR HANDLERS
          $('#hidden_select>option').attr('selected', false);
          $('#hidden_select>option:eq(3)').attr('selected', true);
      } else {
          $('#hidden_select>option:eq(3)').attr('selected', false);
      }
  });
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qnd75wmf/5/

Comment: D'oh. Of course! You're a rock star @Matt. Thanks so much for your help. :)

Comment: You're too nice. Thanks!

Comment: One year later - I'm back! This solution is still exactly what we need (so again, thanks); but this year we're noticing it's not working in Safari.  Any thoughts as to why? I've tried to do some debugging but I'm coming up blank on solutions...hmm.