# How to change value of a drop down list depend on selected radio button?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

How do I get the value of my radio button and used it in my where clause ?

```
        <input type="radio" name="radiobtn" value = "Yes" onclick="GetLockIn();" >Yes
        <input type="radio" name="radiobtn" value = "No" onclick="GetLockIn();" >No

            <select id="reasondd"  name="R" onChange="change_reason()"  width="40" >
            <option id="mySelect" value="" selected="selected" >Select</option> 
            <?php 

                $CheckLockin=$_GET["$CheckLockin"];

                $res=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT DISTINCT discon_reason FROM note_gen2 where lock_in_stat = '$CheckLockin' order by discon_reason asc"); 
                while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {

            ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row['discon_reason'];?>"><?php echo $row["discon_reason"]; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>

     /* FILE AJAX*/
    function change_reason()
    {
    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajax.php?reason="+document.getElementById("reasondd").value,false);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    /* OFFER NO. DROPDOWN */
    document.getElementById("offers").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }


     /* FILE LOCKIN */
    function GetLockIn()
        {
            alert("Do something radio button was checked");
        }
```

ajax .. I want my drop-down to change depends on the selected radio button

```
    <?php require(dirname(__FILE__)."/includes/connection.php");
    $reason=$_GET["reason"];

    if ($reason!="")
    {
                $res=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT offers FROM note_gen2 WHERE discon_reason='$reason'");

                    echo  '<table border ="0" align="top" id="table_data" ><tr><th colspan="0" ></th><th>OFFERS</th><th>YES</th></tr>';


                while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
                {
                    echo  '<tr ><td >'.'<input type="checkbox" name="chkboxoffers" value="'.$row['offers'].'" onchange="updateCheckbox(this);">'.
                          '</td><td >'.'<label id="color" >'.$row['offers'].'</label>'.'&nbsp'.
                          '</td><td >'.'<input type="checkbox" name="radioaccepted" value="'.$row['offers'].'" onchange="updateCheckbox(this);">'.  
                          '</td></tr >';
                }
                    echo '</table>'; 
    }
    ?>
```

I want my drop-down to change depends on the selected radio button

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Dropdown value based on checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41962524/change-dropdown-value-based-on-checkbox)

Comment: nope.. this is connected in a database

Comment: So show us your attemps

Comment: above is my codes

Comment: But not what you have trie to solce your problem

Comment: can you show the ajax function? and what are getting in $row?

Comment: @Darshkhakhkhar khakhkhar I added my Ajax  function

Comment: @Gabriel you have used the "$_GET["$CheckLockin"];" to get the radio button value. but i dont see the form submit anywhere are you sure you are getting the radio button value in "$CheckLockin"; print the variable and also print your query to confirm.

Comment: I want onclick to get the value of the radio button .. on my codes ..I try to used the alert.. but still I don't know how to get the value and used it to my where clause

Answer (score 1):

i have done this work with ajax(with database),
so i send you the code, hope it helps you

```
<input type="radio" name="radiobtn" value = "Yes" class="rdio_btn" >Yes
<input type="radio" name="radiobtn" value = "No" class="rdio_btn" >No

<select id="reasondd"  name="R" onChange="change_reason()"  width="40" >
<option id="mySelect" value="" selected="selected" >Select</option> 

<script>
$(".rdio_btn").on('click' , function(){
     var data = $(this).attr('value');
     var url = /*your url*/;
     var type = /* get or post */;
     $.ajax({
          data:{'data':data , '_token': "{{csrf_field()}}" },
          type:type,
          url:url,
          dataType:'JSON',
          success:function(data){
             $.each(data, function(d)){
                 $("#reasondd").append('<option value="'+data[d].id+'" selected="selected" >'+data[d].name+'</option>');
                 });
             },error:function(e){
                    console.log('error is here');
             }
          )};
     });
});
</script>
```

and your controller should be like this

```
public function functionName(Request $request){
      if($request['data'] == 'yes'{
           return response(/*Your data you wanna send back if user selected yes button in your radio buttons*/);
      }else{
          return response(/*Your data you wanna send back if user selected no button in your radio buttons*/);
       }
}
```

I hope you can use it

Comment: how can I used that on my sql where clause

$res=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT DISTINCT discon_reason FROM note_gen2 where lock_in_stat = '$CheckLockin' order by discon_reason asc");  
                while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {

Comment: @Gabriel this code is for html and jquery , and your question(in comment) is for the controller, you should get data from the controller with your database link , so you should change just the controller codes , all the information you get from your controller get added in your drop down list